# Sum returned values from arrayformula()?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a long list of values in a row that I need to perform several functions/vlookups on, multiply them all together and then sum all the final values. There are over 50 different values in a row so I'm trying to come up with a way to do this without manually typing out vlookups for each column.

Here is the formula I put together, however it seems to not be returning the correct value:

```
=sum(arrayformula(vlookup(offset($A$1,0,{9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54}),Input!$E:$F,2,FALSE)
*offset(indirect("$A"&ROW()),0,{9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54})))
+F6+BD6
```

It's as if it's doing what I want for some of the values, but not summing them all. Debugging this is an absolute pain, so I'm wondering if I'm even going about this in the right way.

Is there a better way to go about this? I'm wondering if the problem is that I've got two sets of arrays embedded in this function.

Comment: There is a much simpler way to do this. If you share a sample sheet, I or someone else can demonstrate how

Comment: It looks like you're trying to convert an excel formula instead of using a simpler Google Sheets way of doing it.